# Forward user back to the previous page after login

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

Can I send my user back to the previous page when he logins in Drupal ?

He can login from different pages in my website. There is not only one login node. I would like to send him back to the page where he was.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out the [Login Destination module](http://drupal.org/project/login_destination). One of the configuration options for that module is "Return user to where he/she came from. (Preserve destination)", and I believe it's enabled by default.

Also helpful is [LoginToboggan](http://drupal.org/project/logintoboggan), which offers a few more login/registration tweaks. LoginToboggan includes an option for a "Login successful" message, which is good way to make sure your newly logged-in users don't get confused when they get redirected back to the previous page.

Answer (score 3):

$form_state['redirect'] is one way to do it. Set it in your submit handler. You could also use the destination URL param. URL?destination=X.